# No webcam detected on dell

Tags: dell, webcam

I recently acquired a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop, model PP29L reference No 07146. It was running Windows Vista with no problems. I decided to get rid of Vista and installed Kubuntu 14.10 32bit. After several days of playing around and getting to know the new OS system I downloaded and installed Skype. The problem is that Skype could not detect my web cam, I also tried Cheese but had the same result, no web cam detected.
I have looked into the System Settings-Hardware-multimedia but nothing there. I spent some time looking at the community help website but found it confusing, lots of different solutions to solve this problem.
I would greatly appreciate if someone can give me an answer to this problem. If it's a case of downloading drivers or software then that's fine. But if it involves file settings then an 'Idiot Guide' will be needed.
Many thanks.
Tom (new user)